# bootstrap :File to import not found or unreadable

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have found already some topics about my problem but I didnt understand how it should be fixed.

I was following http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#fnref-5_5 tutorial and stuck by importing the bootstrap in app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss.

That is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.4'
gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

group :development, :test do
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
end

Gems used only for assets and not required
in production environments by default.
group :assets do
gem 'sass-rails', '3.2.5'
gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :test do
gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end

group :production do
gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

And what error I get on localhost/sample_app/home

```
Sass::SyntaxError in Static_pages#home

Showing c:/Users/katja/Arbeit/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:

File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.
Load path: Sass::Rails::Importer(c:/Users/katja/Arbeit/rails_projects/sample_app/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss)
(in c:/Users/katja/Arbeit/rails_projects/sample_app/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss)
Extracted source (around line #5):

2: 
3:

4: <%= full_title(yield(:title)) %>
5: <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>
6: <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7: <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8: <!--[if lt IE 9]>
Rails.root: c:/Users/katja/Arbeit/rails_projects/sample_app
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:1
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `app_views_layouts_application_html_erb_16020705_20168520'
```

I am using Windows and GitBash. I ahve already tried to delete tmp/cache, it didnt help.
Everything runs perfect but when I add @import "bootstrap"; to a cusom.css.scss, I get an error.

Comment: It worked for me when I put @import "bootstrap" directly inside 'application.css.scss'

Answer (score 8):

Restart the web server "rails s".

Answer (score 0):

i had to restart the server
ps aux | grep rails
kill -9 12345

where 12345 is the process number

(not sure if there is another way to restart rails?

Comment: Not if the server is in the background.  If the terminal is open, you can just use Cntrl-C to kill it.  Otherwise, using 'kill' works.

Answer (score 0):

```
  source 'https://rubygems.org'
  gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

  group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
  end

  Gems used only for assets and not required
  in production environments by default.
  group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', '3.2.5'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.0.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
  end

  gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

  group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  end

  group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
  end
```

add your bootstrap-sass gem into the assets block