# Errno::ENOENT No such file or directory Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, sass

Showing "/Users/Christian/Desktop/sample_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb" where line #5 raised:

> No such file or directory - /Users/Christian/Desktop/vendor/assets
>     (in /Users/Christian/Desktop/sample_app/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
        <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>`
```

I was developing on linux ubuntu and it works fine there, I copied the folder to my mac and it no longer works. custom.css.scss is in the correct location

The problem is on line number 5 :

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>`
```

Comment: Can you show your application.css file?

Comment: Probably some css declared in application.css is missing.

Comment: Here is the application.css 
`/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */`

Comment: Is your vendor directory really under Desktop or is it missing the "sample_app"?

Comment: Mika, my vendor directory is inside sample_app.

Comment: Well, then it is no wonder it is telling you "No such file or directory - /Users/Christian/Desktop/vendor/assets". How does your custom.css.scss file look like?

Comment: I have no idea why it thinks it's in the desktop and how to make it look at the right place.

He is my custom.css.scss

[link](http://cl.ly/code/1M381K1i2s2D)

Comment: I don't know what could cause that but have you seen this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611298/bootstrap-file-to-import-not-found-or-unreadable it seems to have something in common.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change sass-rails version to 4.0.3 and leave the rest as it is. Remove Gemfile.lock when necessary, and then:

```
$ bundle update
$ bundle install
```

Finally, don't forget to **restart** your rails server!

Answer (score 2):

In your Gemfile change the sass-rails version to 4.0.3. Get rid of a version number for sprockets. Delete the Gemfile.lock. Run the bundle install again