# ActionView::Template::Error (No such file or directory - ..../vendor (in ..../rails/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss))

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I have followed the  "Ruby on Rails Tutorial" by Michael Hartl to "5.1.2 Bootstrap and custom CSS."  Basically, I added bootstrap-sass gem on my Gemfile, installed it; added  config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif) to config/application.rb; created the file: app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss, and added the line: @import "bootstrap"; to custom.css.scss.

However, when I tried to run my rails home page on my local rails server, I got the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No such file or directory - /Users/boss/Documents/Aptana/vendor (in /Users/boss/Documents/Aptana/test3/app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss)):
2: <html>
3:   <head>
4:     <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
5:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application.css", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
6:     <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
7:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8:     <!--[if lt IE 9]>
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:5:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__3756317890019596621_70094001398520'
```

Any ideas why I get the error?

Comment: you could write just `stylesheet_link_tag "application"`, do you include your `custom.css.scss` inside `application`?

Comment: How do I include custom.css.scss inside application?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the same issue as this question: [Errno::ENOENT No such file or directory Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25574059/errnoenoent-no-such-file-or-directory-rails-4)

I hit exactly the same problem today and following the advice on the linked question to change the sass-rails version to 4.0.3 fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a Rails 3.2.19 app. The *RAILS_ROOT* was being missed out in the *Sass.load_paths* param causing it to look in */Users/Ian/vendor* rather than */Users/Ian/rails_app/vendor*. In your case it seems it is missing out the */test3* part of the path Turns out it is a 'feature/bug' in the latest sass gem (3.4.2) released on August 29. Adding

```
gem 'sass', '3.4.1'
```

to the Gemfile fixed it. Not sure exactly what the 3.4.2 version of sass is doing though.

Update: I think it is a clash with the bootstrap-sass 2.x gem, with the latest bootstrap-sass gem (3.2.0.2) there is no error with sass 3.4.2. I filed an issue here https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1418 but I don't know if it is sass or bootstrap-sass that is at fault.