# Iterating through all files in a given directory

Tags: ruby, file, ruby-on-rails-4, directory, iteration

I am currently using the [cities gem](https://github.com/joecorcoran/cities) to populate a list of cities in the database for creation of addresses. I have been asked to remove this gem and to read in all the json files from the cities folder that comes with the cities gem.

I have looked at several SO posts regarding how to do implement this, including: [Iterate through every file in one directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512254/iterate-through-every-file-in-one-directory)

Upon implementation wit the `Dir.glob`, my app just completely crashes on that specific page and quits/exits the server.

Otherwise, with `Dir.foreach`, I get

```
Errno::ENOENT in StuffsController
No such file or directory @ dir_initialize
```

For this error, I tried [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25574059/errnoenoent-no-such-file-or-directory-rails-4) but realized that I really can't be updating my Gemfile as it causes more problems for me.

Here is my code that produces `Errno::ENOENT`:

```
@okay = Array.new
Dir.foreach("#{Rails.root}/cities/*.json") do |json_file|
  @okay << JSON.parse(File.read(json_file))
end
```

I have also tried the below code from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28403667/no-such-file-or-directory-rb-sysopen-public-receipts-416981-pdf) but received a

```
NameError in StuffsController
undefined local variable or method `id' for # <StuffsController>


@okay = Array.new
Dir.foreach("#{Rails.root}/cities/#{id}.json") do |json_file|
    @okay << JSON.parse(File.read(json_file))
end
```

I can get it to work for reading a single file from that folder just fine, 100% no problems:

```
@cities = Array.new
@json = JSON.parse(File.read('cities/AD.json'))
@json.each do |j|
  if j.second.has_key?("accentcity")
    @cities << j.second.select {|k,v| k == "accentcity"}
    name = j.second.select {|k,v| k == "accentcity"}
    City.first_or_create(name: name)
  end
end
```

(Please note that the `@cities` array was primarily used for testing whether or not my method produced what I wanted)

I am using Ruby on Rails version 4.2.6.

Comment: What does the log file contains after your app crashes with glob?

Answer (score 6):

[`Dir.foreach`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Dir.html#method-c-foreach) isn't the correct method here. Its parameter should be a directory, not a glob pattern. In your case, it looks for a directory literally called `"cities/*.json"` in your Rails project, which obviously doesn't exist.

If there only are `.json` files in `cities/`, you could use `Dir.foreach("#{Rails.root}/cities/")`

`Dir.glob` should be the correct method. Could you please show us the error message you get when your server crashes?

This code should work, provided all the json files in `"cities"` are valid :

```
@okay = Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/cities/*.json").map do |json_file|
    JSON.parse(File.read(json_file))
end
```

Comment: okay, I tried that but it killed the rails server when I tried to load the index page. (placed it in the index action of a controller).

Comment: is it because I am storing it into an array? Do I need to add it to something else?